# JavaCompiler API force compile with errors?

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm currently making a tool that will output Java class files for use based on user input.  I have outputted a set of .java files, some of which reference classes and variables that don't exist in the current context.  Because of this, when I compile, the output file notes these errors and does not compile the class.  My question is:  Is there a way to use JavaCompiler to compile class files as is?

Here's the compilation code:

```
public static void compileAll(File file) throws IOException{
    String fileToCompile = "C:/test.java";
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    FileOutputStream errorStream = new FileOutputStream("Errors.txt");
    int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, errorStream, "-verbose", fileToCompile );
    if(compilationResult == 0){
        System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Is there a way to use JavaCompiler to compile class files as is?

Yes: create dummy methods and/or dummy classes as needed so you can compile :)

Comment: Better yet, define them as interface and then add the dummy methods implementing them. That way replacing them could be swifter.

Comment: So you're saying there isn't a way to do this?  Because remaking all the necessary classes is going to be a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible, because the Java compiler needs to know the types as well as the names of variables and methods at bytecode generation time.  Because Java bytecode is typed and some Java-source-level conversions are not known to the JVM (e.g., unboxing conversion is purely a Java compiler convention), the compiler cannot get away with emitting bytecode that says "load field `f`" or "call method `foo`"; the compiler must say "load field `f` of type `double`" or "call method `f` of type `int(double, Object)`".

Consider reading an unknown field of an object and assigning it to a `double` local variable:

```
double d = o.f;
```

If the type of `f` is `double`, the compiler will simply use a `getfield` followed by a `dstore` into the local variable slot for `d`.  If `f` is of type `int`, the compiler will emit an `i2d` instruction between the `getfield` and `dstore` to convert the `int` to a `double`.  If `f` is of type `Double`, the compiler will emit a call to `doubleValue()` to unbox the loaded value before storing it.  If `f` is of type `Object`, the assignment is illegal in Java without a cast (which would be a `checkcast` instruction if it were legal).  If the class of `x` doesn't have a field named `x`, there's no possible translation for this assignment.

Similar considerations apply when calling a method with unknown signature, which may require conversions for each of its arguments and/or creating an array for a varargs call.  Further, at the JVM level, overloading on return type is allowed, so even if there's only one list of argument types, the return type must also be specified.

The best you can do is provide dummy declarations of the unknown classes so the compiler knows what to do, as suggested by paulsm4's answer.